# Iteration through RestAPI POST calls

Tags: rest, api, automation, postman

I'm working with a private cloud platform that is used for creating and testing Virtual Machines. They have rich API which allows me to create VMs:

```
{
  "name": "WIN2016-01",
  "description": "This is a new VM",
  "vcpus": 4,
  "memory": 2147483648,
  "templateUuid": "sdsdd66-368c-4663-82b5-dhsg7739smm",
...
}
```

I need to automate this process of creating machines by just simply iterating **-01** part, so it becomes:

- "name": "WIN2016-01",
- "name": "WIN2016-02",
- "name": "WIN2016-03"
  etc.

I tried to use Postman Runner and build the workflow https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/building_workflows/ but with no luck - not sure what syntax I need to use in Tests tab.

Comment: You can set variables within the 'Pre-request Script' tab, then use them on the request itself to make them dynamic. So you can have a number that increments after every request, then convert it to a string (e.g. 2 will become "02"), and append it to your request body.

Comment: Do you think I can have some sort of documentation on this matter? I know how to use pre-request scripts but not sure how to implement this particular solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of doing it.

Create a collection and your POST request.

In your `pre-request`, add the following:

```
/* As this will be run through the Collection Runner, this extracts 
the number of the current iteration. We're adding +1, as the iteration starts from 0.*/ 

let count = Number(pm.info.iteration) + 1;

//Convert the current iteration number, to a '00' number format (will be a string)

let countString = ((count) < 10) ? '0' + count.toString() : 
count.toString();

//Set an environment variable, which can be used anywhere

pm.environment.set("countString", countString)
```

In your POST request body, do something like this:

```
{
   "name": "WIN2016-{{countString}}",
   ...
}
```

Now, run your collection through the 'Collection Runner', and enter the number of ***Iterations*** (e.g. how many times you want your collection to run). You can also add a ***Delay***, if your API imposes rate limits.

Finally, click ***Run***.